# Remove input error message after click on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have a form where i am showing validation error below each input field.

```
<div class="form-group m-0">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address" placeholder="Address">
    <i class="form-group__bar error-red address"></i>
</div>
```

when `Ajax` response have errors regarding to the input field, I shows them here `<i class="form-group__bar error-red address"></i>`.

**What i want if that when the error shows and the user clicked on the input field i want to disappear the error message.**

Is there any library for this kinda things, Cause there are many fields in the form, It will be good where we can use library for every form and field.

Comment: Are not you using _jQuery_?

Comment: Hii, i am using jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use .focusin() function. What you have to do is just give common class to each `<i class="form-group__bar error-red address"></i>`.
like if your common class for each `<i class="form-group__bar error-red address"></i>`   is  "form-group__bar" then you can use focusin like this.

```
$(".form-group input").focusin(function() {
  $(this).siblings(".form-group__bar").hide()
});
```

this will hide error message on focus of input.
For more you can search for focusin and focusout events.

Comment: Much better buddy, Thanks. By the way is there any library for these kinda things ?

Comment: Your welcome @Gamer, there are plugins available like  jquery.validate and  bootstrapValidator. But if your need is small then no need to use plugin. you can write some js and css for that.

Answer (score 1):

use this code no library needed just jquery which you already use

```
$("input").focus(function(){
   $(this).siblings("i.error-red").hide();
});
```

Comment: Okay i got it, Is there any library which i can use i can't use the above code for each and every field.

Comment: just add it at the end of your script and it will select all the input fields automatically  unless you're generating input fields after the document is loaded.

Comment: it will select every present input in the document

Comment: Perfect, Thanks Mate.